# Uniform convergence of $\frac{1}{1+nz}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\bigg(\dfrac{1}{1+nz}\bigg)$ converges pointwise to $f(z) = 0$ on $\mathbb{C}- \{0\}$.

> What is the region of uniform convergence of $\bigg(\dfrac{1}{1+nz}\bigg)$ to $f(z) = 0$?

For any $r>0$ , let $D_r = \{|z|>r\}$.

For any $\epsilon >0,\ $ let N be an integer larger than $\frac{1}{r\epsilon}$.

Then $\forall n\geq N, \forall z\in D_r$, 
$|\frac{1}{1+nz}| \leq |\frac{1}{nz}|<\frac{1}{nr} < \epsilon$.

Hence, the region of uniform convergence is $|z|>r$ for any $r>0$. $\ \ \ \square$

Is this the correct region of uniform convergence?

If we let $z=\frac{1}{n}$, then $\frac{1}{1+nz} = \frac{1}{2}$, which contradicts the above result.

Where did i go wrong? Help please.

> Furthermore, i want to prove that $(\frac{1}{1+nz})$ converges uniformly on any compact subset of the complex plane that does not contain the origin.

Suppose that $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. I want to show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\forall z\in K, |z| \geq \delta$.

I was given the following topological result (without proof) in the introductory course:

> If $f:K\to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, then $|f|$ is continuous and $\max_{z\in K} |f(z)|$ exists.

Let $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$, where $f$ is continuous on $K$. Then, $\exists m = \max_{z\in K} \frac{1}{|z|}$. Hence, $\min_{z\in K} |z|= \frac{1}{m}$ and let $\delta = \min_{z\in K} |z|$.

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't think $\frac{1}{|1+nz|}\leq\frac{1}{|nz|}$ is correct, it's only correct for $Re(z) \geq 0$.

Comment: Note: @Nan and I got that from [Exer 7.22(c)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610950/) of [A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html)

Comment: @BCLC Yes, that's the book I was looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not "the" region, but any of the $D_r$ sets with $r>0$ is a region of uniform convergence. That is: once you fix an $r>0$ you have $D_r$ a region of u.c. But is not true that $\bigcup_{r>0}D_r=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is a region of u.c.: your example actually disproves it. But your example doesn't work on a fixed $D_r$ since only finitely many points of the form $\tfrac1n,\, n\in\mathbb{N},$ are in $D_r$.

Comment: You mean $\tfrac1{n+z}$ or $\tfrac1{1+nz}$ as in the question?

Comment: I think we have infinite $\frac{1}{n}$ on the ball $|z-1|<1$

Comment: Do you disagree with Nan? Nan says $D_r$ works only for $\Re(z) \ge 0$. I guess we could modify to union = $\Re(z) \ge 0 \setminus \{0\}$

Comment: We do have infinite points of $\{\frac1n\in\mathbb C \colon n\in \mathbb N\}$ on the ball $\{z\in\mathbb C\colon |z-1|<1\}$, but this is none of the $D_r$ regions mentioned in the question or in this answer...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last two questions, I believe they are not about $\mathbb{C}$ but about $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.

First, you're own counterexample shows that convergence of $\tfrac1{1+nz}$ to its pointwise limit cannot be uniform in any set containing a neighborhood of $z=0$.

And second, your last statement is just not true. Any compact set containing $z=0$ (for instance any zero-centered closed disc, just to mention a few infinity number of examples) will clearly fail to satisfy the desired $\delta$ property.

Comment: Sorry i mean any compact subset that does not contain the origin.